# Excel: copy rule before last /

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, delimiter, csv

I try copy text before last /

Sample:

- 14501/30305
- 14501/30305
- 14507/39756
- 15936/15943/15954
- 14507/15940/30405
- 15936/15943/15980

Result:

- 14501
- 14501
- 14507
- 15936/15943
- 14507/15940
- 15936/15943

I try somelike this but no work in my excel. Return error invalid formula.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1)),A2,LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1)))
```

Everytime I get issue This formula is invalid:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a clear answer, but you may go this way (I used cell A1 for my example):

1. `= LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"")` - This will count how many `/` you have in A1 cell
2. Then you may use this count in SUBSTITUTE function:
   `= SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"#";LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"")))`
   in order to replace last `/` occurrence with some other *unique* symbol - `#` in my example
3. Use FIND to locate this new symbol starting search from 1st symbol:
   `=FIND("#"; SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"#";LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";""))); 1)`
   it will give you localtion of `#`, i.e. location of last `/` in initial string.
4. Use this location for LEFT function:
   `=LEFT(A1; FIND("#"; SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";"#";LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;"/";""))); 1)-1)`

Comment: Why not a clear answer? I think you explained it quite well. Kudos!

Comment: mmm... it was not clear for me when I started to write it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use multiple ways, for example:

---

`MATCH()` the last occurence of the forward slash:

```
=LEFT(A1,MATCH(2,1/(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)="/"))-1)
```

Or if one does not have Microsoft365:

```
=LEFT(A1,MATCH(2,1/(MID(A1,ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1)="/"))-1)
```

---

`SUBSTITUTE()` the last occurence of the forward slash:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))-1)
```

---

`TEXTJOIN()` any other than last part:

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()<last()]"))
```

---

[image]

---

**Edit:**

If this is done in GS for now, you can use `REGEXEXTRACT()` inside and `INDEX()`:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(^.*)\/")),,)
```

This will spill all your answers down in the same column.

Comment: I can't read that language, but my guess you would need to translate that formula to your own locale *or* you don't have Microsoft365 @Sylvester

Comment: JvdV, can I ask you for help? Can I send you an excel file and can you try to extract everything before last / as in the subject? Because there are about 50,000 records. Thanks!

Comment: @Sylvester, no I'm not doing the work for you. Sorry.

Comment: Sylvester, it looks like you are using Polish version of Excel and probably need to translate all function names to Polish language. Also some functions (like SEQUENCE I think) are available starting from O365

Comment: @StarterKit I try translate to Polish - but still the same issue as in screen. Thank you for the information. I will try to buy a 365 license but it will take me a while. I am sharing a link to doc google. If someone could paste me here result, I would be grateful! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JGW5RstloHvzU5lW0sELCWGJxP1MAlWzVwG2Thg5ZLc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Sylvester, in GS it's a different story, you could try: `=REGEXEXTRACT()`

Comment: Ok, I've put formula in cell C12.

Comment: Also about your excel - I see strange "&" symbol - I'm not sure it should be there. Plus different Excel versions use different argument separator - some use ',' while othere ';' - this may be a problem for you also.

Comment: @ StarterKit thank you for your help  and your hints!  I approved your reply. Now I will learn on all answers to resolve these problems in my Excel. Thanks for all!

Comment: @Sylvester, see my anser in cell `F2` on your spreadsheet. You need just a single formula.

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing in another version of `SUBSTITUTE|RIGHT` in the ring as others have already demonstrated.

`=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/"&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99)),"")`